# How to get the indexes of a mistake in Word's GrammarErrors object

Tags: vsto, ms-office, office-interop

We're trying to use Word's COM objects in order to programatically get the spelling and grammar errors in some sentences. We're using code that looks something like this:

```
foreach (Word.Range range in this.GrammaticalErrors)
  {
    MessageBox.Show(String.Format(
      "Grammatical error: {0}",
      range.Text));
  }

  foreach (Word.Range range in this.SpellingErrors)
  {
    MessageBox.Show(String.Format(
      "Spelling error: {0}",
      range.Text));
  }
```

This works fine for spelling: We print the words that are mistaken. But for grammar, the object seems to return the text of the entire sentence.

Any idea how to get the specific words with a grammar error?